# Is there a bandwidth/speed limitation with MongoDB?

Tags: networking, .net-framework, mongodb

**Is there a bandwidth/speed limitation with MongoDB? Ideally the insert speeds should come near the file transfer speeds, but it’s 1/3 at best.**

Details below.

- **Server**: MongoDB v4.4 community edition, running on Windows 10 Virtual Machine
- **Client**: .NET app using v2.11 .NET Mongo Driver

The application has to save 1.22MB of data every 100 milliseconds, more than that causes latencies in my system, which is very serious. Without using compression it takes ~140ms, with compression it takes ~80ms but the system runs many services so there could be delays, so even the ~80ms is not enough. With compression the transfer speed is ~15MBps at best, but the maximal transfer speed I achieved (using a file transfer to the mongo server computer) gave 50MBps.

The problem is not the mongod data save - while trying to save ~60MB of data the log showed it took ~400ms while the entire transfer took ~5 seconds.

Comment: There is probably not a MongoDB specific issue here. Bottlenecks like this are typically server or network based and can be fairly wide ranging in cause as well as solution.

Comment: `$ seq -f%02.0f 0 99 | while read n; do dd if=/dev/zero bs=1200K count=1 of=./test$n ; done`

Comment: Uh... do that via the same "channel" as your client/server connection.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I suspected network based bottleneck but it has been ruled out since file transfers are as fast as the bandwidth allows. Using the Performance tool, the `System` process that handles file transfer receives 50MBps while the `mongod` process receives only 70KBps

Comment: @Hannu  could you please explain what does the code do? I’m don’t know bash very well

Comment: @Hannu I googled and understood your intention. I will use that idea to test the bandwidth using a simple python program. Will post my findings here

Comment: @DanielLyubin Check out ExplainShell. Great site that will break it down for you. Here, [check it out for details on that one-liner Hannu posted](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=seq+-f%2502.0f+0+99+%7C+while+read+n%3B+do+dd+if%3D%2Fdev%2Fzero+bs%3D1200K+count%3D1+of%3D.%2Ftest%24n+%3B+done).